# Чем величина в информатике отличается от данных

Tags: веб-программирование

есть величины, постоянные и непостоянные .И есть типы данных, так чем они отличаются?
Т.Е  есть типы величин числовые, текстовые и логические. А типы данных тоже имеют типы, например : логический , строковой и.т.д, чем величина от данных отличается?
или это одно и тоже

Comment: Сравнивается что-то несравниваемое. Как "человек" и "200 см"

Comment: типы величин числовые, текстовые и логические. А типы данных тоже имеют типы, например : логический , строковой и.т.д, чем величина от данных отличается?

Comment: Вносите уточнения в сам вопрос - кнопка "править"

Comment: я добавил, вы поможете с ответом

Comment: есть 10 метров, а есть ширина дороги - чем они отличаются друг от друга?

Comment: 10 метров это величина, а ширина тип данных ?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/osnovialgoritmizacii/obavlenia/kurs/azyk-programmirovania-pascal

Comment: Мое понимание. Величина - это какая-то характеристика объекта. Тип данных - тип значения этой величины. Например величина: ширина окна, у которой тип данных строковый. И поэтому получается что величина и тип данных - это не одно и то же. У каждой величины есть свой тип данных, который характеризует ее.